# Move to the beginning of next code block in Vim

Tags: perl, vim

Assuming I have the following Perl code open in Vim:

```
if (@arr = shomething()) {
   for (@arr) {
       some_function($_->{some_key});
       # some
       # more
       # code
       while (some_other_funtion($_)) {
           write_log('working');
       }
   }
}
```

and the cursor at the beginning of the line with `some_function`, how I can move the cursor to any of:

- the start of the `while`
- the `{`  of the `while`
- the first line inside the `while` block (with the call to `write_log`)

Searching for `{` is not an option, because there could be many of `{` that do not start new inner code block - for example, see parameter of `some_function`.

Comment: Have you tried searching with `/`? I feel like this would be a good first step

Comment: There could be other '{' between cursor and start of next block.
I'd like to get know about commands (native or via some plugin), like ]], [], ]} and friends.

Comment: I would suggest either `/while<return>` or `/write_log<return>` if you don't like `)`, `]]`, and such... Or maybe switch to `gvim` for point-n-click, or make sure your terminal and `vim` setup enables mouse interaction...

Comment: Seems I was not clear enough.
I like `]]` and friends, but I do not see such command to find beginning of next block.
Regarding `gvim` - thanks, but this is not an option for me. Only console, only hardcore :)

Comment: `[{`, `[[`, and i{` text objects are great for find section/blocks that you are currently in. Find a deeper nested section/block is the trick. You may be interested in the [targets](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) plugin

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are defining a “code block” to be `{` `}` that contain at least one line. You can most easily search for those just by searching for a `{` at the end of a line:

```
/{$
```

`/{` means search for a `{`, and `$` represents an anchor to the end of the line.

There might be cases where a `{` opens a block, but is not the last character of a line:

```perl
while (some_other_funtion($_)) { # this while is very important
   write_log('working');
}
```

To take this into account, do the following search for a `{` that is not closed on the same line:

```
/{[^}]*$
```

1. `/` – search for
2. `{` – a `{` character
3. `[^}]` – followed by any character that is not a `}`
4. `*` – repeated 0 or more times
5. `$` – until the end of the line

([Vim regexes](http://vimregex.com/) are not always the same as in Perl, but this particular one is.)

You could define a mapping for that second search by putting this in your `.vimrc`:

```
noremap <Leader>nb /{[^}]*$<CR>
```

That would let you jump to the next block by pressing [`<Leader>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3CLeader%3E) (<kbd>\</kbd> by default) <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>.

Since it uses [`:noremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:noremap), it affects [Select mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Select) too. You won’t want that if your `<Leader>` is a printable character (which it is by default). In that case, add the line [`sunmap <Leader>nb`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:sunmap) below the previous line to fix Select mode.

Comment: According to your link, `\=` is *0 or 1* matches, not *0 or more*.

Comment: Just `/{` is sufficient if you don't care about the opening brace being the last character. Or `?{` if you want to search to the previous brace.

Answer (score 0):

% , $, and ^ are your best friends. (cursor to matching enclosure, end of line, beginning of line).

At the beginning of your code block there ':1$' , will put your cursor at the first bracket.

%  will advance you to the next 'matching' end of your code block, assuming it is balanced. If your code is out of balance, the cursor won't move. It actually counts matching-type opening and closing braces which follow and if there is an imbalance, the cursor will not move. Usually the terminal will beep: as in 'Doh! You have a problem.' It's very useful and it works with '{}[]()'

Good way to check your code and ensure that the end of the block exists. It will skip as many lines as exist between the braces (or parens or brackets) to place the cursor on the matching enclosure.

This file is small but assuming you're on line 1 (:1)

:1$ - end of line first code block

```
:2 - puts the cursor at the 'f' in 'for' on line 2 rather than the white space preceding.
%  - jumps you to the closing ')' on that line. 
%  - jumps you to the opening '(' on that line.
$  - takes you to the '{' which opens the for loop code
%  - jumps the cursor to the ending '}' of the for loop
%  - takes you back to the top (% is bi-directional. )
```

Play with it. There's a reason that Intellij's text editor has a vim mode. It's powerful.

Also, pretty good vim manual here that covers some of this stuff and much more.

[https://www.pks.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.1/suselinux-manual_en/manual/sec.suse.vim.html](https://www.pks.mpg.de/%7Emueller/docs/suse10.1/suselinux-manual_en/manual/sec.suse.vim.html)